# Console.ReadLine() retornando nulo antes de digitar

Tags: c#, .net

Sou iniciante, estou fazendo um curso de C# e este é o código:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
namespace Course
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Entre o número da conta: ");
            int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Entre o titular da conta: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            BankAccount account = new BankAccount(id, name);
            Console.Write("Haverá depósito inicial? (s/n) ");
            char yesOrNo = (char) Console.Read();
            while (yesOrNo != 's' && yesOrNo != 'n')
            {
                Console.Write("Insira (s/n) ");
                yesOrNo = (char) Console.Read();
            }
            if (yesOrNo == 's')
            {
                Console.Write("Entre o valor de depósito inicial: ");
                account.Deposit(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Dados da conta:");
                Console.WriteLine(account);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Dados da conta:");
            Console.WriteLine(account);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("Entre um valor para depósito: ");
            account.Deposit(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            Console.WriteLine("Dados da conta atualizados:");
            Console.WriteLine(account);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Entre valor para saque: ");
            account.Withdraw(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 5);
            Console.WriteLine("Dados da conta atualizados:");
            Console.WriteLine(account);
        }
    }
}
```

BankAccount.cs:

```
namespace Course
{
    internal class BankAccount
    {
        private double _balance = 0;
        public int Id { get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public BankAccount(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
        public double Balance
        {
            get
            {
                return _balance;
            }
            set
            {
                _balance = Math.Round(value, 2);
            }
        }
        public void Deposit(double amount)
        {
            if (amount > 0)
            {
                Balance += amount;
            }
        }
        public void Withdraw(double amount)
        {
            if (amount > 0)
            {
                Balance -= amount;
            }
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Conta {Id}, titular: {Name}, saldo: R$ {Balance:F2}";
        }
    }
}
```

Porém, quando a execução chega nessa parte:
[image]
Antes de eu digitar qualquer coisa, o seguinte erro aparece na linha 34 do Program.cs: `System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'`
Já tentei criar uma variável para receber o valor de `Console.ReadLine()` e depois passá-la como argumento, mas acontece o mesmo erro.

Comment: O método `double.Parse()` espera um número em formato válido, e provavelmente `Console.ReadLine()` está retornando algo fora do esperado. Tente usar `double.TryParse()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813188/8133067

Answer (score -2):

O problema é que voce esta utilizando o `Console.Read()` da maneira errada.

```
 char yesOrNo = (char)Console.Read();
```

Ele retorna o próximo caracter que está no buffer, ou seja, não é indicado para voce utilizar para capturar apenas 1 tecla de entrada do usuário.

Faça o seguinte teste.

```
Console.Write("Digite alguma coisa:");

char primeiroCaracter = (char)Console.Read();

Console.WriteLine("Primeira Tecla: " + primeiroCaracter);

Console.WriteLine("Restante: " + Console.ReadLine());
```

Se o usuário digitar por exemplo '123', a saída sera:

```
Digite alguma coisa: 123
Primeira Tecla: 1
Restante: 23
```

Isso porque o `ReadLine` retorna todos os caracteres que está no buffer, se voce utilizar o `Read` para exibir o restante, voce iria precisar chamar mais 1 vez para exibir o valor '23'

No seu caso, é bem provável que no momento que voce solicitou 's' ou 'n', o usuário informou uma tecla e pressionou Enter. Isso são duas entradas do usuário.

```
 account.Deposit(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Nesse momento `Console.ReadLine()` ainda tinha para liberar o valor de Enter.

[Isso está documentado aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-8.0#coment-rios)

Concluindo, o ideal seria utilizar `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` onde será lido apenas 1 tecla e sem a necessidade de ser pressionado Enter ou então o próprio `Console.ReadLine`

Comment: Perdão pela pergunta boba, mas o que é buffer?

Comment: Resumindo seria uma area de armazenamento temporario. Imagina que sempre que o usuário pressiona alguma tecla, essa entrada é armazenada em um local pelo sistema operacional antes dela ser processada por alguma aplicação.